# How do I bind CheckMenuItem.selectedProperty() to another ObservableValue?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, menuitem

I want to bind a `CheckMenuItem`'s `selectedProperty` to another observable value, like `cmi.selectedProperty().bind(myObs)`. However, this is not possible, since the framework sets the selection property when the check menu item is clicked (see [line 1394](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/956e47b045b3/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/ContextMenuContent.java#l1394) of ContextMenuContent.java).

Is there a way to intercept the click—so that I can do my own custom processing—and still bind the selection property to another observable?

I suppose I'm thinking of the click as a request to update some state. The user clicks the menu item, then the program attempts to change some state accordingly, and the selection changes if the state successfully updated. Under 'normal' conditions, the check should toggle upon every click; however, if something bad happens, I'd prefer that the check doesn't toggle and instead reflects the true state of the program.

Comment: "Binding" means that the selected property would *always* be equal to the value of the property to which you want to bind it, which is simply inconsistent with allowing the user to change the value. So it's not really clear what you want to do here. Probably either you should bind the selected property and disable the check menu item, or you should use a listener on the observable value instead of a binding. (Or possibly you have the wrong approach entirely...?)

Comment: I've added another paragraph; hopefully that better explains what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this (without getting into writing a skin for the menu item) is to roll your own menu item with a graphic. You can just use a region for the graphic and steal the CSS from the standard modena stylesheet. Then bind the visible property of the graphic to the observable value, and toggle the observable value in the menu item's action handler:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VetoableMenuItemWithCheck extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar() ;
        Menu choices = new Menu("Choices");

        // observable boolean value to which we're going to bind:
        BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        // graphic for displaying checkmark
        Region checkmark = new Region();
        checkmark.getStyleClass().add("check-mark");

        // bind visibility of graphic to observable value:
        checkmark.visibleProperty().bind(selected);

        MenuItem option = new MenuItem("Option", checkmark);

        choices.getItems().add(option);

        Random rng = new Random();

        // when menu item action occurs, randomly fail (with error alert),
        // or update boolean property (which will result in toggling check mark):
        option.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (rng.nextDouble() < 0.25) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that", ButtonType.OK);
                alert.showAndWait();
            } else {
                selected.set(! selected.get());
            }
        });

        menuBar.getMenus().add(choices);
        root.setTop(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("check-menu.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and

check-menu.css:

```css
.check-mark {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-color;
    -fx-shape: "M0,5H2L4,8L8,0H10L5,10H3Z";
    -fx-scale-shape: false;
    -fx-padding: 0em 0.11777em 0em 0em;
}
```

There may be a simpler approach, but this seems not too bad.

A version for a vetoable radio menu item could follow the same basic idea, but with

```
ObjectProperty<MenuItem> selectedItem = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

and then for each menu item do

```
checkmark.visibleProperty().bind(selectedItem.isEqualTo(option));

option.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (successful()) {
        selectedItem.set(option);
    }
});
```